# Group by in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

On SQL Server 2014, I have a table `visits(id_visit, date, id_person)` I cant figure out a way of getting the id_ of the last visit for each person in an aggregate function

don't really know if it can help but here is kind of what i'd like to have

```
select *
from visits
where id_visit in (select id_visit, max(date) from visits group by id_person)
```

If i had like visits (id_visit, id_person, date)
1,1,'2017-07-17'
2,1,'2017-01-01'
3,2,'2016-01-01'
4,2,'2015-01-01'
5,2,'2013-01-01'
i'd like it to return  1,3,5

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_person ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
  FROM visits
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

It will return last visit per person.

Comment: Looks like its working, and how would you introduce that if i had some and clauses in my main where ?

Comment: @BastienMorel Just andd them after `rn=1 AND ...`

Answer (score -1):

You Need on more subselect:

```
SELECT *
  FROM visits
 WHERE id_visit IN (SELECT id_visit
                      FROM visits 
                     WHERE date IN (SELECT max(date) 
                                      FROM visits 
                                     GROUP BY id_person))
```

Comment: that's what i thought but i didn't succeed in doing it properly thank you

Comment: does it do what you want? then maybe mark as anwer ;D

Comment: i got one problem left, if i have a and b visiting at the same date then b visiting later on, it will show me both b's visits while i only want the second one to appear